# How can I use angular arrays/ lists effectively

Tags: arrays, angular, list

So I am building analytics for a site. I am pulling data from an a rest API and feeding it into an angular front end.

I have arrays like these in my `.component.ts` file:
    ***Array 1***

```
this.statsPassed24Hrs = [
{'Description': 'Total A', 'Count': this.a},
{'Description': 'Total B', 'Count': this.b},
{'Description': 'Total C', 'Count': this.c},
{'Description': 'Total D', 'Count': this.d},
{'Description': 'Total E', 'Count': this.e}
];
```

***Array 2***

```
this.statsPassed7Days = [
{'Description': 'Total A', 'Count': this.aPassed7Days},
{'Description': 'Total B', 'Count': this.bPassed7Days},
{'Description': 'Total C', 'Count': this.cPassed7Days},
{'Description': 'Total D', 'Count': this.dPassed7Days},
{'Description': 'Total E', 'Count': this.ePassed7Days}
];
```

***Array 3***

```
this.statsPassedMonth = [
  {'Description': 'Total A', 'Count': this.aPassedMonth},
  {'Description': 'Total B', 'Count': this.bPassedMonth},
  {'Description': 'Total C', 'Count': this.cPassedMonth},
  {'Description': 'Total D', 'Count': this.dPassedMonth},
  {'Description': 'Total E', 'Count': this.ePassedMonth}
];
```

As you can see through out in all the arrays the `'Description'` remains the same whilst the `'Count'` is the only thing that changes.

I want to be able to maybe use one array an manipulate it. I just do not think that creating a dozen lists will be a good solution

Any ideas or guidance will be appreciated.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a property in the Array as follows:

```
this.statsPassedMonth = [
  {'Description': 'Total A', 'CountMonth': this.aPassedMonth, 'Count24Hrs': this.a, 'Count7Days':this.aPassed7Days},
  {'Description': 'Total B', 'CountMonth': this.bPassedMonth, 'Count24Hrs': this.b, 'Count7Days':this.bPassed7Days},
  {'Description': 'Total C', 'CountMonth': this.cPassedMonth, 'Count24Hrs': this.c, 'Count7Days':this.cPassed7Days},
  {'Description': 'Total D', 'CountMonth': this.dPassedMonth, 'Count24Hrs': this.d, 'Count7Days':this.dPassed7Days},
  {'Description': 'Total E', 'CountMonth': this.ePassedMonth, 'Count24Hrs': this.e, 'Count7Days':this.ePassed7Days}
];
```